# Feedback tab like www.monyta.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, user-feedback

I am interested in adding a stick feedback tab to be hosted on my page. No third party ones like uservoice, monyta, getsatifaction.. etc.

It should be sticky while scrolling vertically and the tab should slide out showing a form to be filled out and submitted, very much like monyta.

Any JQuery plugins (or plain Javascript) which do this? Want one which is mostly done and not you-can-do-this-yourself stuff.

Comment: Have you tried looking at how the third-party ones work?

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the **[jQuery "Tab slide Out" Plugin](http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/09/jquery-tab-slide-out-plugin/)**. It does virtually everything you demanded.

You can take a look at the demo [here](http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html).

There is even a [demo](http://wpaoli.building58.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/feedback-panel.html) with integrated AJAX form available, along with the according [blog post](http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/08/jquery-animated-feedback-tab-thingy/)

Comment: This plugin cannot be used on multiple items on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Give FeedbackTab a try.

It's free to use and works with a simple JavaScript widget. Jquery 1.41 or higher is needed.http://www.feedbacktab.org.